# UIViewController inside UIViewController - IBAction not firing

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ibaction

I have a UIViewController (ViewController A) taking the screen and I want to add a small UIViewcontroller (ViewController B) to act as a header of the parent ViewController (ViewController A).

On ViewController A I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:self.test.view];
}
```

On ViewController B I have a test button:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTest:(id)sender
{
}
```

This buttonTest never gets called. Any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.test.view];
}
```

Declare the variable *test as class level to keep it stay in the life cycle.